# Odd behavior matching powers of pi

Tags: pattern-matching

I have a long list of generated values from which I want to remove "weird" ones like `Sin[Sin[1]]` and `Pi^2/4`.  However, trying to remove the powers of `Pi` fails on this value:

```
MatchQ[Sqrt[2 Pi], (_ Pi)^_] (* False *)
```

The `FullForm` of the expression is

```
Power[Times[2, Pi], Rational[1, 2]]
```

I can only match the expression when I explicitly specify the `2`:

```
 (_Integer Pi)^_  (* False *)
 (2 Pi)^_         (* True *)
```

What's going on here?

Comment: I found out what's happening, but I don't know *why* it's happening.  Points to anyone who can explain.

Comment: An interesting question would be: when does `(x y)^power` automatically split into `x^power y^power` and when does it stay together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little more digging resulted in the answer: my pattern is being evaluated to

```
 Pi^_*_^_
```

Using `HoldPattern` prevents this behavior and gives the expected result:

```
MatchQ[Sqrt[2 Pi], HoldPattern[(_ Pi)^_]] (* True *)
```

Comment: Interesting! I would not have hit me, that the `Power`-rules are applied even for patterns. Good find!